# how to display Each record 4 for each id column

Tags: mysql

```
id  serviceid   name  cost   date
201  15          X      50    25.12.2016
201  15          Y      55    29.11.2016
201  120         Z      50    27.11.2016
201  19          w      50    22 .11.2016
201  158         p      50    23.11.2016
201  18          q      50    21.11.2016
201  16          rs     50    24.11.2016
201  81          rs     50    2.11.2016
202  18          X      50    25.12.2016
202  18          Y      55    29.11.2016
202  15          Z      50    27.11.2016
202  19          w      50    22 .11.2016
203  15          p      50    23.11.2016
203  18          q      50    21.11.2016
203  16          rs     50    24.11.2016
0    81          rs     50    2.11.2016
```

Desire Output :

```
id  serviceid   name  cost   date
201  15          X      50    25.12.2016
201  15          Y      55    29.11.2016
201  120         Z      50    27.11.2016
201  16          rs     50    24.11.2016

202  18          X      50    25.12.2016
202  18          Y      55    29.11.2016
202  15          Z      50    27.11.2016
202  19          w      50    22 .11.2016

203  15          p      50    23.11.2016
203  18          q      50    21.11.2016
203  16          rs     50    24.11.2016

0    81          rs     50    2.11.2016
```

i want to display each record 4 - 4 record service for each id i am trying to apply using self Join but there is Problem coming please tell or suggest  me how to ac-chive for this.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable AS a
WHERE 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable AS b 
  WHERE b.id = a.id and b.serviceid >= a.serviceid) <= 4
ORDER BY a.id   , a.date
```

this query am trying but i am unable to fetch it for each id there should top 4 service id based on date.

Comment: This will require simulating row number, which MySQL doesn't have.  But besides that, you need to give us the logic by which 4 records per group are being retained.

Comment: yes i have to get for each id top 4  serviceid based on top date like my desire output

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is not possible in mysql ? can u please suggest me

Comment: You most likely would need some dynamic SQL to handle this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have tried this but  each time it gives 4 suppose i want to increase this data then i am unable to increase

Answer (score 0):

To make your desired result, I think you should use mysql variable like this:

```
select
    t1.*
from mytable t1
join (
    select
        `id`,
        `serviceid`,
        `name`,
        `cost`,
        `date`,
        @rowno := case when @grp = `id` then @rowno + 1 else 1 end as rowno,
        @grp := `id`

    from mytable
    cross join (select @rowno:=0, @grp:=null) v
    order by `id`, `date` desc) t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.`date` = t2.`date`
and t2.rowno < 5
```

and this seems to be a classic top x record in each group issue, take a look of [**How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL**](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Comment: but id 203 is coming 6 time while in view only 3 times

Comment: Did you run this script based on your sample data? @SrjoanJee

Comment: and when i put <7 then it  201 comes 11 time while it should 7 times onlye

Comment: NO actually i have view  i am executing according that